# Email attachments in PHP

Tags: php, email, email-attachments

On my site, I have an option to create a pdf file and send it as an attachment in an email.

```
$document = new Dompdf();
$document->loadHtml($file_content);
$document->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$document->render();
$output = $document->output();
file_put_contents('../docs/purchase_orders/'.$file_name.'.pdf', $output);

$file = '../docs/purchase_orders/'.$file_name.'.pdf';
$content = file_get_contents($file);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$subject = "New Purchase Order.";

$headers = "From: sales@example.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: sales@example.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: sales@example.com" . "\r\n";

$message = "--".$uid."\r\n";
$message .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

$message_header = file_get_contents("../mail/email_header.php");
$message_content = file_get_contents("../mail/new_purchase_order.php");
$message_content = str_replace('%supplier_name%', $supplier, $message_content); 
$message_content = str_replace('%file_name%', $file_name, $message_content); 
$message_footer = file_get_contents("../mail/email_footer.php");

$message .= $message_header.$message_content.$message_footer . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$file_name.".pdf\"\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . "\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name.".pdf\"\r\n";
$message .= $content."\r\n";
$message .= "--".$uid."--";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

This seems to work fine, as in our sales email that is BCC'd receives the email and can open the attachment with no issues.

However, external users who are receiving the email directly (as in `$to`) sometimes have issues opening the file.

See attached screenshot:

[image]

I know there are external libraries that will make sending emails and attachments easier (like PhpMailer) but would like to know why this is happening or what I could do about it.

Comment: After further investigation, this seems to be mainly happening with outlook email accounts.

Comment: Its tough doing this all by yourself. Have you considered using a Mailer framework which does all the dirty work for you? (Like PHPMailer)

Comment: @paskl, thanks for your comment, I was hoping to try figure this out myself without the use of something like that (i'd rather learn what is actually going wrong) although if I can't resolve this I might have to.

Comment: So further investigation reveals it wasn't just Outlook accounts it's happening for yahoo as well we just hadn't got any reports of it. Basically it seems to be working for gmail accounts (tested both an account on our domain and an external @gmail.com address)

Comment: Unless you read all of RFC2821 etc. to replicate what PHPMailer already does correctly; **no**. Those manual MIME multiparty construction copypastas are not worth fixing. (See abundance of similar prior questions).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this must be something to do with the encoding of the file (base64)